# Is Subversion client 1.8.4 fully supported in NetBeans 7.4?

Tags: svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, netbeans-7

Is Subversion client 1.8.4 fully supported in NetBeans 7.4? I recently update to TortoiseSVN 1.8.3 using NetBeans 7.3 and I received errors, stating only TortoiseSVN 1.7 was supported.

Comment: Related article http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversion1_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that NetBeans has its own internal Subversion client, presumably 1.7.x from your question.

The working copy for a 1.8.x Subversion client is not compatible with the working copy for a 1.7.x Subversion client as stated in the 'Upgrade Working Copy' section here - http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple and good solution for getting Netbeans 7.3 to work with Subversion 1.8 can be found [here](http://www.shayanderson.com/microsoft-windows/make-netbeans-731-work-with-subversion-18.htm) (until they upgrade the Netbeans plugin).

Answer (score 0):

[Faq Subversion 1.8](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversion1_8)

- Q: Is Subversion client in version 1.8 supported?
- A: NetBeans 7.4 and older support Subversion 1.8 only through commandline client.

The [FaqSvnJavahl](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSvnJavahl) and [FaqSubversionClients](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionClients) pages also give good insight to NetBeans Subversion support.